# master sheet in excel for cricket player statistics

Tags: excel

I am trying to combine cricket player statistics into one master sheet. I have 3 worksheets with player points.

sheet 1. Points for runs 
sheet 2. Points for catches 
sheet 3. points for wickets

I want to total the amount of points for each player into a fourth sheet.

I have combined all of the values from sheets 1,2 and 3 into a final 4th sheet and have got many duplicate names. This is how it looks:

A1:Joe Bloggs,    B1:10 
A2:Joe Bloggs,    B2:15 
A3:Joe Bloggs,    B3:20

Joe Bloggs would have 10 points for runs, 15 for catches and 20 for wickets. The result I am looking for is to have sheet four look like this:

A1:Joe Bloggs, B1:45

The player may have points from all three sheets (catches,wickets and runs), or from only one/two sheet/s. This means there could be 3 Joe Bloggs like above, 2 Bob Taylors, and 1 Peter Smith (in no particular pattern).

Is there an easy way to total the player statistics so the names don't repeat in sheet 4?

Comment: For us to be able to help you properly, you have to describe what each table looks like

Comment: Sorry was trying to give a bit of a background to the problem and may have just made it more confusing. I have produced a final sheet (sheet 4). Currently it has combined the values into this kind of format A1:Joe, B1 10, A2: Joe, B2, 15. I want to remove the duplicate rows so that it only has A1:Joe, B1: 25. The problem is the data doesn't repeat the pattern of having two of each player. There may be 3 Bob Taylors and his points, and only 1 Ronald Mcdonald and his points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to make it so your 4th sheet only has 1 of each player, then using this formula and dragging down on your 4th sheet will do the sums for you:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,A1,Sheet1!B:B)+SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,A1,Sheet2!B:B)+SUMIF(Sheet3!A:A,A1,Sheet3!B:B)
```

Comment: Thanks Dane. This worked a treat. I was considering doing this manually so you have just saved me hours/days of time!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest summing the values in the cells in sheets 1-3 in a cell in sheet 4.  For example, if all of Joe's data is in cell A1 of sheets 1-3, you could have something like:

```
=SUM(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A1,Sheet3!A1)
```

in whichever cell in sheet 4 you'd like the total.

When you use the SUM function, you could simply click on the cells you wish to include in the sum with commas in between.

This will work if the numeric values are in their own cells, rather than part of a text cell along with Joe's name.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem is the player lists are not identical across the 3 different sheets. For instance, Joe Bloggs might be in cell  A15 on wickets, but on A16 for catches, and not even exist in the runs sheet.

Comment: Also the values are in separate cells, E.g A1 Name, B1 points